# UWP binding to custom dictionary

Tags: c#, uwp, binding, uwp-xaml

I have a ViewModel which works in UWP, all bindings are working except my custom dictionary and I don't know why. Nothing shows up.

I'm using FodyWeavers hence the shorthand notation. The custom dictionary returns the key with a * behind it if the key isn't found.

**In the ViewModel**

```
public static TranslationDictionary Translations { get; set; }
```

**In the view**

```
 <TextBlock Text="{Binding Translations[Test_Translation]}" />
```

**Custom Dictionary**

```
public class TranslationDictionary : Dictionary<string, string>
   {
       public new void Add(string key, string value)
       {
           if (value == null)
           {
               return;
           }
           base.Add(key, value);
       }

       public new void Remove(string key)
       {
           if (!ContainsKey(key))
           {
               return;
           }
           base.Remove(key);
       }

       public new string this[string key]
       {
           get
           {
               string value;
               return TryGetValue(key, out value) ? value : key + "*";
           }
           set
           {
               if (value == null)
               {
                   Remove(key);
               }
               else
               {
                   base[key] = value;
               }
           }
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this result by using x:Bind instead of Binding

An overview of the difference between x:Bind & Binding [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/data-binding-quickstart)

And so declaring a static class looking like that :

```
public static class DictionariesOperations
{
    public static string GetValue(Dictionary<string, string> dict, string key)
    {
        return dict[key];
    }
}
```

And then in your xaml :

```
<TextBlock Text="{x:Bind local:DictionariesOperations.GetValue(Translations, Test_Translation)}" />
```

Hope this help =)